# Order Mysql query by Name and other fields

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, group-by, group-concat

I have a question about MySQL. I have a Table with this fields:

- WorkerName
- Date
- HoursWorked

Ok, if I do this Query:

```
SELECT WorkerName, Date, HoursWorked, SUM(HoursWorked) FROM myTable GROUP BY WorkerName
```

I have the field grouped by the Worker Name BUT with a only row. I want to show all days worked by this Worker in the same row, and the other Worker in another row.

In PHP actually have a While that shows all days worked, but only shows the Hours of the first day sorted.

Comment: This sort of grouping operation is best done in the presentation layer of your application—i.e. within PHP.  If you absolutely *must* do it in the database layer, you might consider using MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function—e.g. `SELECT WorkerName, GROUP_CONCAT(Date), SUM(HoursWorked) FROM myTable GROUP BY WorkerName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  WorkerName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Date) AS dates_worked,
  SUM(HoursWorked)
FROM
  myTable
GROUP BY
  WorkerName
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but this concat it in a only row, I want multiple rows to display it in PHP. For example: Name dates_worked 1 dates_worked 2... dates worked 30 SUM_hours